# apt-get update not working (Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80])

Tags: 11.04, apt, software-center

When I try to run apt-get update I get the following error messages: 
I am using:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:    11.04
Codename:   natty




W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used
```

I have tried few solutions:

1. Like choose the best server from Ubuntu Software section : It was never able to select the best server as it gave error (Check your internet connection.) My internet is working fine and I am able to browse.
2. `sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`
3. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Nothing worked. 
I am not able to post the full error message as its not letting me post more than two links.

Comment: You 120% sure that after the second solution it didn't work apt-get update? Could you do `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` **edit** your question and add the results?

Comment: I got the following error after second solution.  
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
But I am able to proceed further. Thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Sometime 'sudo apt-get update'  solves all the life`s problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Natty no longer supported or gets updates.
You need to change from the **archive.ubuntu.com** to the **old-releases.ubuntu.com** server, which is the intention of the sed command you mentioned (I have not had chance to confirm if that works or not).
Open and replace all entries in the following file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then after run the update and upgrade commands as you would normally.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. keep getting on old-releases
WARNING:root:file 'oneiric.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.

Tried various mirrors, none wants to play ball upgrading natty to oneiric.

Comment: As of 2015 this doesn't work anymore. Sucks that ubuntu is such a clusterfuck of complexity that it can't sustain slightly older releases. Gonna try to convince my admin to switch to OpenBSD.

Comment: This [partially] worked for me with the "zesty" release.